# Fetch sum of variables in component controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

I have a list of question with answers on scale from -1 to +2 displayed in a button group (SLDS).

## Component

```
<aura:component access="global" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="getChartData" >

<!--Question-->
     <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account"><a href="javascript:void(0);">
        <ui:outputText value="{!v.firstName}"/>
        actively supports and guides me in the current sales campaign.</a>
    </div> 

 <!--Scale-->
    <div id="Q1" class="slds-button-group" role="group">
      <lightning:button aura:id="Q1btn" class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border slds-is-selected" 
     title="Dont know yet." label="?" />
      <lightning:button aura:id="Q1btn" class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border" label="-1" 
     title="Little awareness and involvement" value="-1" onclick="{!c.buttonScore}" />
      <lightning:button aura:id="Q1btn" class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border" label="0" 
     title="Some organizational awareness" value="0" onclick="{!c.buttonScore}"/>
      <lightning:button aura:id="Q1btn" class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border" label="1"
     title="Limited involvement" value="1" onclick="{!c.buttonScore}" />
      <lightning:button aura:id="Q1btn" class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border" label="2"
       title="Strong involvement" value="2" onclick="{!c.buttonScore}"/> </div>

    </aura:component>
```

## Controller

```
buttonScore : function(component,event,helper){
   var btnClicked = event.getSource();
   var btnId = btnClicked.getLocalId();
   var btnValue = btnClicked.get("v.value");
   //console.log('btnID-->'+btnId+'  '+btnValue);
   var a,b,c,d,e,f;

   if(btnId == "Q1btn"){
       a = parseInt(btnValue);

   }
    if(btnId == "Q2btn"){
       b = parseInt(btnValue);
       console.log('a-->'+a);
       console.log(a+b);
   }
     if(btnId == "Q3btn"){
       c = parseInt(btnValue);
   }
     if(btnId == "Q4btn"){
       d = parseInt(btnValue);
   }
      if(btnId == "Q5btn"){
       e = parseInt(btnValue);
   }
      if(btnId == "Q6btn"){
       f = parseInt(btnValue);
      <!--How to get sum here?(a+b+c+d+e+f)-->
   }
  },
```

[image: One example below]

Similiarly I have many question and I want the sum of all the scales added dynamicall in the client side controller itself. Since onclick of the scale option is a button event, the values get refreshed everytime I click and gives incorrect value. What approach should I take ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can save value in an attribute on every button click. And then on click of next button get that value and add new value in it.

```
buttonScore : function(component,event,helper){
   var btnClicked = event.getSource();
   var score = component.get("v.score");
   var btnId = btnClicked.getLocalId();
   var btnValue = btnClicked.get("v.value");
   //console.log('btnID-->'+btnId+'  '+btnValue);
   var a,b,c,d,e,f;

   if(btnId == "Q1btn"){
       a = parseInt(btnValue);
      component.set("v.score",score+a);
   }
    if(btnId == "Q2btn"){
       b = parseInt(btnValue);
       console.log('a-->'+a);
       console.log(a+b);
      component.set("v.score",score+b);
   }
     if(btnId == "Q3btn"){
       c = parseInt(btnValue);
       component.set("v.score",score+c);
   }
     if(btnId == "Q4btn"){
       d = parseInt(btnValue);
component.set("v.score",score+d);
   }
      if(btnId == "Q5btn"){
       e = parseInt(btnValue);
component.set("v.score",score+e);
   }
      if(btnId == "Q6btn"){
       f = parseInt(btnValue);
component.set("v.score",score+f);
   }
  },
```

Comment: Thanks.. So obvious don't know why it didn't cross my mind..